# WooCommerce specifc variations for specific user role

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

i want to make a product variation that only can be seen by specific user roles.
I tried this code but it didnt work for me...

Can someone help me?

```
function user_has_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {

                if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
                    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
                else
                    $user = wp_get_current_user();

                if ( empty( $user ) )
                    return false;

                    return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );}



                if ( taxonomy_exists( $name ) ) {
                    $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, $name, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    continue;
                    }
                if($name == 'ermaessigt' && $term->slug != 'normal' ) { // or whatever your attribute is called, and whatever the attribute term is called. 
                    if(!user_has_role('administrator')){
                    continue;
                    }
                }
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                }
                } else {
                    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                    if($name == 'pa_weight' && $option != '1kg' ) { // or whatever your attribute is called, and whatever the attribute term is called. 
                    if(!user_has_role('aziende')){
                    continue;
                    }
                    }

                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
                    }
                    }
```